# Readium js viewer config language

Tags: config, readiumjs

How do i configure the language from readium js viewer to translate the buttons in the audio player. 
[image]

This is my current configuration:

```
    config : {
    'readium_js_viewer/ModuleConfig' : {
        'fonts': fontsArray,
        'useSimpleLoader' : false, 
        'epubLibraryPath': undefined, 
        'canHandleUrl' : false,
        'canHandleDirectory' : false,
        'workerUrl': undefined,
        'epubReadingSystemUrl': undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 
`navigator.userLanguage = 'es'` or the language that you want